# Claims in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: api, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a JS application that targets one of applications in my AzureAD b2c directory.
In the signin policy, i have included email along with few other claims that are to be returned.
But When i get access token and used that to access one of API(API is also an application in Azure AD b2c directory), the authorization works fine but in claims, there is no email claims.
How to add that to access token ?

Moreever , i would also like to add roles and other custom claims to user and then those being returned in access token.
What process i need to follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom Claims in Azure AD B2C are only available in the id_token.**

If a Web API secured by Azure AD B2C wants to access extra information about the user, the Web API will need to [query the Azure AD Graph directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Note: At this time, the Azure AD Graph can only be achieved using the client credentials flow (in other words, using the application's identity, not the users).

I would recommend that you request any features in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am more clearer with client credentials now

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind upvoting / marking the question as answered? :)

Comment: I have been able to get custom attributes in access token using graph APIs